# emacs hurts my wrists, how to make ' into Meta?

Tags: emacs

i bound caps lock to Crtl in the system keyboard configurations, but how do i rebind a normal key to a modifier key, after rebinding that normal key to a lesser used key?

ie bind `\` to `'`, and `'` to `Meta` correctly (eg `Shift ' .` is `Meta >` and everything works just as if `'` were `Meta`).

with this symmetric Crtl/Meta keyboard layout, my hands feel less like contortionists, thus happier.

i've tried vim, but it's modal, so i prefer emacs.

EDIT: if impossible, why doesn't emacs let you do this?

Comment: it's not strictly an answer, but you can try this - http://xahlee.org/emacs/ergonomic_emacs_keybinding.html

Comment: Try [sticky keys](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/StickyModifiers) so you don't have to twist your hand. It allows pressing keys in multi-keycombos one after the other. It's very convenient when you get used to it.

Comment: @Tom very good idea! ergonomic for everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "'") esc-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "'") esc-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "\\") (lambda () (interactive) (insert-char ?' 1)))
```

The only problem is that you can't hold down Shift-'-> at the same time.  You have to hit ' then Shift-> to get the behavior you want.

Comment: thanks. i'm still looking for the behavior of, for example, holding meta and clicking f a few times to move through a sentence fast.

Comment: Yes, this is a partial solution that is not quite ideal.  I wasn't able to find any true solution to match what you were looking for.  It might be a good question for the emacs-devel mailing list as there are some real gurus on there; just keep the question short and too the point and see what you get.